# How to display Unicode characters in VB6?

Tags: unicode, vb6, chr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best option to display Unicode text (hebrew, etc.) in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540361/whats-the-best-option-to-display-unicode-text-hebrew-etc-in-vb6)

What is the correct way to display the unicode character `9646` (BLACK VERTICAL RECTANGLE) in VB6?

When I try `ChrW(9646)` it displays `?`.

Comment: Question marks are encoding problems, you'll get them when the Unicode string is converted to Ansi.  Post a code snippet.

Comment: @CJ7 There are many *black vertical rectangles*.. So most importantly what **Language** are you trying to do this `Unicode` *juggling*? According to the chosen language you may set your `Font.Charset` and `Font.Name` properties.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [tutorial](http://cyberactivex.com/UnicodeTutorialVb.htm) to explore. Take a look at this article for the [black vertical rectangle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ae/index.htm).

Assuming Unicode is turned on, send the following string to a window to display:

`Wchar_t mStr[] = {9646,0,0};`

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/454574/How-to-show-special-characters-in-an-Edit-Control). This code snippet and reference is more inlined with C++. Where you would turn off/on UNICODE in Visual C++ using following steps:

1. Open your project in VS2008/2010;
2. Right click the project in Solution Explorer and click Properties;
3. Select `Configuration Properties-> General`, select `Character Set` and change the `current value` to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`. (turning off)

---

**Good article aboubt [displaying UNICODE in VB](http://www.example-code.com/vb/vbUnicode1.asp)**.

When you are working with a `textbox` control in a `Form`, add the `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` as a reference library. This component **provides Unicode supportted controls**, such as: textbox, label, command button,list box, combo box, checkbox, radio button, toggle button, image, tabstrip, and multiple page control.

Working with VB6 and displaying non-us-ANSI characters you need 3 main things to understand:

- Internally, VB6 stores strings as Unicode.
- When displaying a string, the **standard VB6 textbox and label controls** do an implicit (and internal) conversion from Unicode to ANSI.
- The **standard VB6 textbox and label controls** display the ANSI bytes according to a character encoding that you can specify.

After the `Unicode-to-ANSI` conversion, VB6 then attempts to display the character data according to the control's `Font.Charset` property, which if left unchanged is equal to the ANSI charset. Changing the control's `Font.Charset` changes the way VB6 interprets the "ANSI" bytes. In other words, you're telling VB6 to treat the bytes as some other character encoding instead of "ANSI".

For e.g. consider trying to display a `Unicode Japanese` string on an `English` computer: You set the `Font.Charset = 128` (for Japanese), but your Unicode string displays as all question mark characters. It's because VB6 is first trying to convert your Japanese Unicode string to ANSI, which is [Windows-1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx) for English computers. Japanese characters are not representable in Windows-1252. Each character fails to convert and is replaced with a question mark. **for e.g. Selecting the Japanese script in the TextBox control's property settings is the same as setting the Font.Charset at runtime.**

As **Jukka said** `Font` plays a vital role showing UNICODEs given the availability of the characters within a Font. As Hans said, `glyph` unsupported Font produces a rectangle. So you need to make sure the `Font` you select is capable of **rendering glyphs**. For e.g. `MS Sans Serif` font does not render `ƒ` (LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK, 2-byte Unicode value is 0x0192), so you'll see a **thin solid rectangular box** in its place. However on Windows, there are very few fonts with a wide enough character repertoire to represent Chinese..

**In the following code the Font Name () is set during Run Time along the Font CharSet**

Charset properties:

```
134     Simplified Chinese, gb2312 - Mainland China(PRC) and Singapore
136     Traditional Chinese, big5 - Taiwan and Hong Kong
```

Code:

```
Sub changeToUniCodes()
Dim strTxt2 As String    

UserForm1.TextBox2.Font.Charset = 134    '--CHINESESIMPLIFIED_CHARSET
UserForm1.TextBox2.Font.Name = ChrW(&H5B8B) + ChrW(&H4F53) '-- 宋体 SimSun font

UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = ChrW(37446)
strTxt2 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
'notice that ChrW(9246) produces a different character in Chinese
UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = strTxt2 & " " & ChrW(9246)
End Sub
```

Output in VBE IDE: You may give it a try in VB6 form as well.

[image]

After all the above writing, I noticed this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/transformations-of-unicode-code-points) article. Well at least it's VB confirmation :D

Comment: What do you mean "assuming Unicode is turned on"?  How is it turned on?

Comment: @CJ7 please take a look at the updated answer with code snippet and comment. :) Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use "Unicode aware" controls.  VB6 only came with a few of these, though in Vista and later or XP (Tablet Edition only unless you use the non-Ink redist version of this library) the InkEdit control can do this.

```
InkEdit1.Text = ChrW$(9646)
```

Note the `$` which indicates a function returning a String instead of a Variant with one embedded in it.

An InkEdit control is really an enhanced RichTextBox that supports ink entry as well as typing on ink-enabled systems.  It is also a Unicode control, and one that supports Unicode properties such as `.Text`.

The standard MSHFlexGrid, DataGrid, and a few other controls are also Unicode-aware.

See http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html for characters like the one in question.  You can basically ignore the jibber-jabber about ANSI, Charset, etc.  It is relevant but not applicable here.

`▮ 9646 ▮ 25AE   BLACK VERTICAL RECTANGLE`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it displays a question mark is that the character is not present in the font being used. You need to set the font to [one that supports BLACK VERTICAL RECTANGLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ae/fontsupport.htm), such as Arial Unicode MS or Lucida Sans Unicode.

Comment: A missing glyph produces a rectangle, not a question mark.